# Why I am getting multiple rows instead of single row of a particular date from database while I am trying to get sum of revenue as Date Wise

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a table which sum the total revenue of a particular date, but using the following code I am getting multiple row each date instead of single row: -

```
$date = $row['date'];

$t_fee = mysql_query("SELECT sum(labs.test_fee), sum(labs.discount), sum(labs.received) from labs join patients on labs.p_id = patients.p_id where date = '$date'");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($t_fee)) {

    
    $fee_sum = $row[0];
    $discount_sum = $row[1];
    $received = $row[2];
    $after_discount = $fee_sum - $discount_sum;
    $balance = $after_discount - $received;
```

---

```
-----------------------------
Date        | Total Revenue |
-----------------------------
2017-05-23  |   1,000       |
2017-05-19  |   4,190       |
2017-05-19  |   4,190       |
2017-05-19  |   4,190       |
2017-05-18  |   1,350       |
2017-05-08  |   690         |
2017-05-02  |   2,280       |
-----------------------------
Grand Total |   9,510       |
-----------------------------
```

I want to get results like this: -

```
-----------------------------
Date        | Total Revenue |
-----------------------------
2017-05-23  |   1,000       |
2017-05-19  |   4,190       |
2017-05-18  |   1,350       |
2017-05-08  |   690         |
2017-05-02  |   2,280       |
-----------------------------
Grand Total |   9,510       |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: `...where date = '$date' GROUP BY date"`

Comment: or select distinct (date)....where date = '$date'

Comment: you have to use mysqli extension instead of mysql, because this extension is deprecated since php 5.5.x version. Also if the `$date` is entered by the user you should use PDO or prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

Comment: maybe you want this SELECT date as 'Date', sum(revenue) as 'Total Revenue' FROM your_table group by date;

Comment: Still getting same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 where date = '$date' 
 group by date;
```

you need to group by date so append `group by date;` in the query.